# How to define a new scope to a function scopes

Tags: javascript, function, variables, scope

I wonder if there's a way to define a varibles to a function local `[[Scopes]]` for example the following function

```
//Parent function has a global scope {Window}
function x() {
  //Local variable, closure to function {x}
  var a = 123;
  //Local function which have access to all {x} local scope like {a}
  function y() {
    console.log(a)
  }
   //Check the function y scope {window, Closure(x){a=123}
  console.dir(y)
}
x()
```

the function above `Scopes` should to be like that

```
0: Closure (x) {a: 123}
1: Global {window: Window, self: Window, document: docume...
```

which can access `window object` and it's parent `closures` like `a`

another example for a local function which has 3 `Scopes` when using `eval()`

```
//Parent function has a global scope {Window}
function s(obj, fn) {
  //Local variable and closure to {s} function
  var q = 123
  if (typeof fn === 'function') {
    /*
     - {y} here is local function which before {eval} have 2 scope
    - {window}, closure (s) {obj: {a: "a", b: "b", c: "c"}, q = 123}

    - after using of eval it's will get a new scope {block} scope Which will allow this function to access everything like obj, fn, y itself, q everything inside the parent function not just a Closure scope for things used on it like {q} and also it's will change 
     * closure (s) {obj: {a: "a", b: "b", c: "c"}, q = 123}
     - to 
     * closure (s) {arguments: Arguments(2) [{…}, ƒ, callee: ƒ, Symbol(Symbol.iterator): ƒ], fn: ƒ (), obj: {a: "a", b: "b", c: "c"}, q: 123, r: 989
     - the new closure will add everything even if it's not used on {y}

    */
    function y(a) {
        console.log(obj.a, q)
    }
    //That's will add a new scope to function {y} and change closure scope of it
    eval('var r = 989')
    //check {y} scope
    console.dir(y)
  }
}
s({
  'a': 'a',
  'b': 'b',
  'c': 'c'
}, function() {console.log('i am a global function')})
```

the function `y` above have access to `x` arguments, vatiables, blocks like `y` function the `Scope` the of function above will be like that

```
0: Block (s) {defVar: ƒ}
1: Closure (s) {obj: {…}, q: 123, arguments: Arguments(2), fn: ƒ, defVar: ƒ, …}
2: Global {window: Window, self: Window, document: docume...
```

but if i have the following functions

```
//global function
//scrope = {window}
function x(fn) {
  var q = 123;
  //here's i want to define q var a local scope of {fn} 
  //like fn['[[Scopes]]']['1'] = 'Closure (x) {q: 123}' so when calling q from {fn} it's will return the q value i want to define it with the same name not like argument
  console.log(fn())
};
//global function
//scrope = {window}
//i want to allow var q of {x} function to be used inside this function normally like 
//function(){var t = "i'am a global function"; return t, q }
//the example above will return Uncaught ReferenceError: q is not defined
x(function(){var t = "i'am a global function"; return t, q })
```

2 functions above will be in the global scope `window` so is there's a way to add new scope to function something like `fn['[[Scopes]]']['1'] = 'Closure (x) {q: 123}'` or `fn['[[Scopes]]']['1'] = x['[[Scopes]]']['1']` i know that `[[Scopes]]` cannot be accessed as property but it's just example

another example

```
// i want to do here the same at comments in example above
function x(fn) {
  var q = 123;
  y()
};
function y(){return 'str'}
```

is there's a way to set a new closures to the function `y` from function `x` like `y['[[Scopes]]']['1'] = {a = 123, b = 456}`

all i want to do is to set a local varibles to a function from another one or allow a global function to access cloures of another function

- the last example to be more clear
- the following function select html elements with presented key, value
- i want when use the optional function to access the variables declared in `selectElements` method or define it to the optional function

> HTML

```
<nav>
    <ul class="nav-items">
        <li class="nav-active"><a href="/">Home</a></li>
        <li class="nav-item"><a href="#nav-active">Fruits</a></li>
        <li class="nav-item"><a href="#nav-inactive">Veggies</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

```
 function selectElements(obj, fn) {
      var sel = {
        'class': function(el, arg) {
          if (arg) {
            return document.getElementsByClassName(el)
          } else {
            return 'document.getElementsByClassName("'+el+'")'
          }
        },
        'id': function(el, arg) {
          if (arg) {
            return document.getElementById(el)
          } else {
            return 'document.getElementById("'+el+'")'
          }
        },
        'tag': function(el, arg) {
          if (arg) {
            return document.getElementsByTagName(el)
          } else {
            return 'document.getElementsByTagName("'+el+'")'
          }
        }
      }
      if (typeof fn === 'function') {
        var closureHanlder, text = ''
        //console.dir(fn, defVar)
        for(var i in obj) {
          obj[i].replace(/^\./, function(elem) {
            elem = obj[i].replace(/^\./, '');
            elem = sel.class(elem);
            text += 'var ' + i + ' = ' + elem + ';\n'
          }).replace(/^\#+/, function(elem) {
            elem = obj[i].replace(/^\#/, '');
            elem = sel.id(elem);
            text += 'var ' + i + ' = ' + elem + ';\n'
          }).replace(/^\w+/, function(elem) {
            if (!elem.startsWith('undefined')) {
              elem = sel.tag(elem)
              text += 'var ' + i + ' = ' + elem + ';\n'
            }
          })
        }
        console.log(text)
        //decalre the elements with variables name 
        eval(text)
        console.log(nav, navActive, navItem, navContainer)
        // i want this function to get the declared elements as local variables or access them from this function {selectElements}
        fn()
      }
    }
    var el = {
      'nav': 'nav',
      'navActive': '.nav-active',
      'navItem': '.nav-item',
      'navContainer': '.nav-items'
    }
    selectElements(el, function () {
      //here i want to access those varibles 
      //console.log(nav, navActive, navItem, navContainer)
      // as a local varibles or access them from the function wheich used on it 
    })
```

Comment: Some modern JS things: don't use `var`. Use `let` or `const`, both block-scoped, instead of the function-scoped `var`. It makes reasoning about scope a million times easier. Also, never use `eval()`, not even for example code. It hasn't had a place in JS for over a decade now. And then on a posting note: to make it easier for folks to understand where you think which scope applies, put some comments in your code so that when you talk about which scopes exists, you can use labels that people can see reflected in your code. That way, we can understand what you're thinking.

Comment: `let`, `const` won't make any deferant in here i want to define a new variable to a global functtion from another function or allow a global function to access closures of another global function when used inside of it i added some cooments to the code  i hope that's explain better

Comment: so just set a property on [globalThis](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/globalThis)? But much, much better would be to write a normal data store (even if it's just `localStorage`) and using that to store and retrieve values that need to exist outside of normal code paths.

Comment: i dont want to use `localStorage` i want to direct call local variable from anothe function i don't want this var to be global var i want to set new local variable to a function from another function as local variable something like `define var` then change it's value then use it do you understand me ?

Comment: No, I don't. Maybe that's the language barrier, but I have no idea what you're asking in your post, and your comments aren't helping making it clearer for me.

Comment: i added the last example i can't be clear more than this

Comment: hope you understand what i want now

Answer (score 0):

To the best of my knowledge you can't. For starters `[[Scopes]]` is not a standard internal slot of any `function` object nor is it of ANY object for that matter. So at best you would be looking at a solution for Chrome only and it most certainly wouldn't be available through javascript.

There's also very little to be gained here. The function wouldn't know about what other variables you are including into its scope. If you are hoping to add a scope that's constant then there's no point to it either since you could just add the respective declarations to the respective function.

This is why `with` failed to provide any real value while also making you question whether any identifier is also being shadowed by the new dynamic context.

Comment: You mean there's no way to achieve that at this time 

Comment: Not to my knowledge plus is highly unlikely that will ever happen.